# SSRS expression output shift upward

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

**Somehow the expression output shifting up few rows.
Any ideas what cause this problem?**

[image: SSRS Design]

[image: Report]

Comment: It looks like it is "filling" vertically in absence of other rows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding a Rectangle to the report area, and moving both the Table and the text boxes to the Rectangle and see if that fixes the problem. Another method may be to add another column to the report table and populate the values conditionally based on the values in the Medication field.